# Why is Vercel failing to build my Next.js tsx app?

Tags: next.js, vercel

When I run npm run build and npm start on my local machine it deploys perfectly to localhost but when I try to deploy the very same code to Vercel I get the following error:

```
08:28:16    Failed to compile.
08:28:16    ./pages/index.tsx:5:20
08:28:16    Type error: Cannot find module '../components/layout' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

It definitely seems like an issue with the Layout component, I switched around the order of the important and it always fails when trying to load the Layout component. Here's the code for the component:

```
import Alert from "./alert";
import Footer from "./footer";
import Meta from "./meta";

type Props = {
  preview?: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const Layout = ({ preview, children }: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Meta />
      <div className="min-h-screen">
        <Alert preview={preview} />
        <main>{children}</main>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

index.tsx line 5 looks like this `import Layout from "../components/layout";` and I've confirmed that that is the correct path for the Layout component.

Comment: are you sure the file name is layout.tsx not Layout.tsx

Comment: @Nikhilbhatia thanks for the suggestion, I triple checked and the file name is layout.tsx

Comment: and your index.tsx is in root folder also your component folder is also in root folder? can you share the file tree of your project

Comment: @Nikhilbhatia It is in the `pages` folder and Layout is in the `components` folder, both in the same root folder.  I used this template from Vercel for the blog, the structure is pretty close to identical: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/blog-starter-typescript

Comment: seems fine here, check Alert, Footer and Meta, may be some wrong inside these components

Comment: i am importing same way like you, https://github.com/nikhilb2/shopmate no prob in deployment my-nextjs-app.nikhilb2.now.sh

Comment: @Nikhilbhatia thanks for looking into this, it's truly baffling. I looked into Alert, Footer, and Meta and nothing was out of place. The odd bit is it works locally but not on Vercel which leads me to think that Typescript and Vercel aren't playing well together,

Comment: why I asked about capital letter file, because my macOS is not case sensitive but linux is, so my project worked locally but when i was trying to deploy, i got similar prob

Comment: @Nikhilbhatia you were 100% correct. Although my local file had a lowercase filename `layout.tsx` my GitHub repo was stuck with `Layout.tsx`! Please feel free to submit the answer below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you sure the file name is layout.tsx not Layout.tsx :-)

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same thing.
Fix layout.tsx to Layout.tsx
The file name and component name must be the same.