# Cannot find module or type declarations while it works in local build

Tags: next.js, vercel

I keep getting this error when trying to build my app on Vercel, while it works locally without problems.

Here is the error message

`Cannot find module Type error: Cannot find module './sidenav/SideNav' or its corresponding type declarations.`

At this line

`import SideNav from "./sidenav/SideNav"`

While import this works fine in the same component

`import NavigationBar from "./navigationBar/NavigationBar"`

My SideNav is nothing special

```
const SideNav = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <div></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SideNav;
```

Any idea on what the problem could be?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why is Vercel failing to build my Next.js tsx app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64226021/why-is-vercel-failing-to-build-my-next-js-tsx-app)? Make sure the import matches the path of the file exactly (including casing).

Comment: @juliomalves I know it is right, because it run `npm run build` locally and it does not give an error about that. It also shows the component on the page so it works

Comment: That's not necessarily true. The case sensitivity of the file system depends on the machine you run it - MacOS is case-insensitive while Linux is case-sensitive. This could explain why it works locally but not on Vercel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some testing, changing the folder to `./sideNav/SideNav` instead of `./sidenav/SideNav` works even if the initial import naming was correct in the name

Answer (score 16):

I was facing this issue too. After initial commit, I renamed a folder from `./src/Provider` to `./src/provider` making my Github builds fail. Clearing my git cache and re-committing somehow fixed the problem.

```
git rm --cached -r .
```

Comment: I'm on a mac and I finally realized that even though my local files had correct casing, when I looked in my remote github repo, the files were still an older casing. This command worked for me (followed by `git add . && git commit -m 'fix casing' && git push`).

Comment: Thank you. This resolved my issue. I renamed a folder, and git did not track the new name which caused an issue when deploying to AWS Amplify.

Comment: helped me aswell, wanted to change ./components/ filenames to capital case instead of camelcase and builds were throwing erros, although it was fine when runing npm run build locally

Answer (score 0):

The error maybe also because of the OS you are using.

E.g, if using mac, folder and file names are case-insensitive, so if you are not using the same case as the file, it will work fine locally, but when you deploy it to vercel, case causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with @Hosni Bara answer, But if you don't want to recomitt you can simply use

```
git mv -f Oldname newname
```

Example

```
git mv -f ./src/views/spreadsheet/UpdateSheetDatavalidator.ts ./src/views/spreadsheet/UpdateSheetDataValidator.ts
```

Its because of git cache issue