# Vercel Build Through Github Fails But Works Through Vercel --prod

Tags: github, webpack, next.js, vercel

I have my github repo connected to my `vercel` build for my `next.js` project, and it auto builds whenever I push to the repo. However, I get this error whenever the `Github-deployment` builds:

> ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components_nt/tracking/formContent' in '/vercel/path0/pages'
> Build error occurred
> Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
> at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:390:19
> at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
> error Command failed with exit code 1.
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
> Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1

I have tried redeploying, reinstalling my next and `node_modules`, and clearing the build cache. None of these work for the GitHub way.

However, for some odd reason, if I run `vercel --prod` then it builds properly and works, but I don't know why. I would appreciate doing the Github way as it is less hassle and more streamlined.

Has anyone else ever experienced this issue? Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you show your `components_nt/tracking` folder structure? This could be a casing issue with the import paths. Make sure the paths exactly match the names of the files you're importing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module or type declarations while it works in local build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68056264/cannot-find-module-or-type-declarations-while-it-works-in-local-build)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to clear the git cache. Quite a interesting error with a simple fix

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).